# Can't open new window when click button

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I need to redirect to new window by using onclick openNewWindow . I just route to my controller but seems it give error as "Route [sla.slaCategoryTreeListScreen] not defined"

**Here is my controller code.**

```
 public function slaCategoryTreeListScreen() {



        return view('sla.slm.SLACategoryCheckBoxList');
    }
```

my view onclick part

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right" type="button" title="Search Category" onclick="openNewWindow('{{ route('sla.slaCategoryTreeListScreen') }}" >
```

my route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'sla'], function () {


   Route::resource('sla', 'SlaController');
  //Route::get('sla','SlaController@slaCategoryTreeListScreen')->name('SlaController.slaCategoryTreeListScreen');

  // Route::get('sla','SlaController@SlaCategoryTreeListScreen')->name('sla.SlaCategoryTreeListScreen');

   Route::get('sla/getbranch/{id}','SlaController@getBranchAjax')->name('sla.getBranchAjax');
    Route::get('sla/getBranchAjax2/{cuid}/{stid?}','SlaController@getBranchAjax2')->name('sla.getBranchAjax2');
});
```

The comment part on route that are trying was not fix at all..Sorry for my bad English and i hope its help.

Comment: Ucomment route with name "sla.slaCategoryTreeListScreen" in route file. and then which error you are facing?

Comment: Use like this ````redirect()->away('REDIRECT_URL')```` in the controller

Comment: The error gives was "Route [sla.slaCategoryTreeListScreen] not defined" ... I already do uncomment part but the new error was Route sla.index not defined

Comment: You need to debug the code like when you click on anchor link then the route with name "sla.slaCategoryTreeListScreen" is called or not?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: `Route::resource()` does only register routes by a predefined array of defaults (`'index', 'create', 'store', 'show', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy'`).
It will **not** automatically register any method from your controller.
Also make sure that your controller has methods for all these routes or specify a subset of routes. Check this for more information: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes

Second: Your a-tag seems to be malformed. The JavaScript method opens with `('` but is never closed again. So it should be like this:

```
onclick="openNewWindow('{{ route('sla.slaCategoryTreeListScreen') }}')"
```

To simply open the URL in a new tab you could use this (with `target="_blank"`):

```
<a href="{{ route('sla.slaCategoryTreeListScreen') }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right">Search Category</a>
```

Additionally: make sure that a route named `sla.slaCategoryTreeListScreen` exist. Easiest way to do so is by listing all available routes by running the command `php artisan route:list` from the root directory of your project in a terminal.

Comment: Thanks....just check from my console that i got syntax error in js ..... and i just made correction from my web route like this "Route::get('sla/slaCategoryTreeListScreen','SlaController@slaCategoryTreeListScreen')->name('sla.slaCategoryTreeListScreen');"

Answer (score 0):

Replace this in your view file

`<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right" type="button" title="Search Category" onclick="window.open('{{ route('sla.SlaCategoryTreeListScreen') }} ', '_blank')" >`

Comment: Uncomment this route ````Route::get('sla','SlaController@slaCategoryTreeListScreen')->name('SlaController.slaCategoryTreeListScreen');````